# Simple Android app - SQLite - SQL has stopped

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I was writing an app using Android Studio. It's simple app for exercises.
I was sure it will work, but no. Something is wrong.
I will paste my code here:

```
package programowanie.android.sql;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper db;

    EditText editTextImie;
    EditText editTextNazwisko;
    EditText editTextTelefon;
    EditText editTextEmail;
    EditText editTextUlica;
    EditText editTextKod;

    Button btDodaj;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        editTextImie = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextImie);
        editTextNazwisko = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNazwisko);
        editTextTelefon = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTelefon);
        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editTextUlica = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUlica);
        editTextKod = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextKod);

        btDodaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btDodaj);

        btDodaj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean czysieudalo;
                czysieudalo = db.wstawdane(editTextImie.getText().toString(), editTextNazwisko.getText().toString(), editTextTelefon.getText().toString(), editTextEmail.getText().toString(), editTextUlica.getText().toString(), editTextKod.getText().toString());
                if(czysieudalo){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Udało się!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Niestety nie udało się :(!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is my DatabaseHelper class:

```
    package programowanie.android.sql;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by Kudłaty on 2016-02-19.
 */
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String database_name ="Kontakty";
    public static final String database_table ="Osoby";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, database_name, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table" + database_table + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, IMIE TEXT, NAZWISKO TEXT, NUMER_TELEFONU TEXT, EMAIL TEXT,  ULICA TEXT, KOD_MIASTO TEXT");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST" + database_table);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean wstawdane(String imie, String nazwisko, String nr_tel, String email, String ulica, String kod ){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("Imie", imie);
        cv.put("Nazwisko", nazwisko);
        cv.put("Nr telefonu", nr_tel);
        cv.put("Email", email);
        cv.put("Ulica", ulica);
        cv.put("Kod pocztowy", kod);
        if (db.insert(database_table, null, cv)==-1){
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

I have no errors, but when I'm trying to add Record app stopping and I get "SQL has stopped"

I forgot to paste Log! Here u are!

```
02-19 18:02:43.119 2087-2087/programowanie.android.sql I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
02-19 18:02:43.195 2087-2087/programowanie.android.sql W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/programowanie.android.sql-1/lib/x86
02-19 18:02:43.348 2087-2115/programowanie.android.sql D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
02-19 18:02:43.410 2087-2115/programowanie.android.sql I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-19 18:02:43.544 2087-2115/programowanie.android.sql W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-19 18:02:43.544 2087-2115/programowanie.android.sql W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabdff300, error=EGL_SUCCESS
02-19 18:03:19.132 2087-2087/programowanie.android.sql E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "tableOsoby": syntax error
02-19 18:03:19.133 2087-2087/programowanie.android.sql D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-19 18:03:19.133 2087-2087/programowanie.android.sql E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: programowanie.android.sql, PID: 2087
                                                                         android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "tableOsoby": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create tableOsoby(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, IMIE TEXT, NAZWISKO TEXT, NUMER_TELEFONU TEXT, EMAIL TEXT,  ULICA TEXT, KOD_MIASTO TEXT
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1674)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1605)
                                                                             at programowanie.android.sql.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:21)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
                                                                             at programowanie.android.sql.DatabaseHelper.wstawdane(DatabaseHelper.java:31)
                                                                             at programowanie.android.sql.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:43)
                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Missing ) after at end of create table command?

Comment: Yeah! Thanks for that adivce.
But now I can't add any Record. I have my Toast "Nie udało się :(".

Comment: Though you get an error on the insert, it is possible that the data was actually inserted. Can you check that? Also try playing with `insertOrThrow` or `insertWithOnConflict`. Also, make sure the are opening and closing the db.

Comment: I got an that error: `Error inserting Kod pocztowy=helmut Imie=helmut Nr telefonu=helmut Nazwisko=helmut Ulica=helmut Email=helmut
                                                                         android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "pocztowy": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Osoby(Kod pocztowy,Imie,Nr telefonu,Nazwisko,Ulica,Email) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)`

Comment: I think that with column names with space you have to use quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this

```
 @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("create table" + database_table + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, IMIE TEXT, NAZWISKO TEXT, NUMER_TELEFONU TEXT, EMAIL TEXT,  ULICA TEXT, KOD_MIASTO TEXT");
        }
```

to this

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + database_table + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, IMIE TEXT, NAZWISKO TEXT, NUMER_TELEFONU TEXT, EMAIL TEXT,  ULICA TEXT, KOD_MIASTO TEXT);");
}
```

you had no spaces between 'table and (ID' so your command would have been

```
 "create tableOsoby(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, IMIE TEXT, NAZWISKO TEXT, NUMER_TELEFONU TEXT, EMAIL TEXT,  ULICA TEXT, KOD_MIASTO TEXT"
```

which wont run.

Also I noticed you forgot the ) and you have forgotten the ; at the end of the statement.You must remember the ; for security reasons

Comment: yeah I've spotted it after posting this question. But thanks. Problem was in missing ) at the end.

But now I can't add any record :/

Answer (score 1):

Given the error log:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "tableOsoby": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create tableOsoby(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, IMIE TEXT, NAZWISKO TEXT, NUMER_TELEFONU TEXT, EMAIL TEXT,  ULICA TEXT, KOD_MIASTO TEXT

I identified here two issues that probably led the SQLite to crash:

1) On the line `db.execSQL("create table" + database_table + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, IMIE TEXT, NAZWISKO TEXT, NUMER_TELEFONU TEXT, EMAIL TEXT,  ULICA TEXT, KOD_MIASTO TEXT");` it is missing a space between the "create table" string and the table name variable, resulting in "create tableOsoby". Same occours with the next concatenated string.

2) The closing parenthesis is missing in the string `"(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, IMIE TEXT, NAZWISKO TEXT, NUMER_TELEFONU TEXT, EMAIL TEXT,  ULICA TEXT, KOD_MIASTO TEXT"`.

The corrected line should be:

`db.execSQL("create table " + database_table + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, IMIE TEXT, NAZWISKO TEXT, NUMER_TELEFONU TEXT, EMAIL TEXT,  ULICA TEXT, KOD_MIASTO TEXT)");`